# ActiveMQ doesn't use jboss.bind.address on Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, activemq-artemis, wildfly-11

I'm trying to setup a simple cluster with two nodes and my application uses JMS.

I tried start the nodes using command:

```
standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\scope-na\e-commerce\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone_no2 -Djboss.bind.address=10.50.17.211 -Djboss.node.name=ecommerce_02
```

Server start with this warning:

```
2019-09-25 18:56:14,305 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to "Matriz_IPxxx_Win2012R2_Sql". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
```

Then I got many errors like that:

```
2019-09-25 18:35:59,937 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-7 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@d82718b)) AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 13: http://Matriz_IPxxx_Win2012R2_Sql:8080
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3387)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3236)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3155)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:673)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:663)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1036)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1076)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1254)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:795)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:685)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionBridge.createSessionFactory(ClusterConnectionBridge.java:136)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1054)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried bind address with -b and using system-properties:

```xml
<system-properties>
    <property name="jboss.socket.binding.port-offset" value="10"/>
    <property name="jboss.node.name" value="ecommerce_02"/>
    <property name="jboss.bind.address" value="10.50.17.211"/>
    <property name="jboss.bind.address.private" value="10.50.17.211"/>
    <property name="jboss.bind.address.unsecure" value="10.50.17.211"/>
    <property name="jboss.bind.address.management" value="10.50.17.211"/>           
</system-properties>
```

Relevant configuration details follow...

**messaging-activemq** subsystem:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="TabelaMensagens" entries="java:/jms/queue/TabelaMensagens"/>
        <jms-queue name="SendGateway" entries="java:/jms/queue/SendGateway"/>
        <jms-queue name="TransacaoAProcessar" entries="java:/jms/queue/TransacaoAProcessar"/>
        <jms-queue name="TransacaoProcessada" entries="java:/jms/queue/TransacaoProcessada"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

**socket-binding-group**

```xml
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="private" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="private" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.modcluster.multicast.address:224.0.1.105}" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

**interfaces**

```xml
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="private">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.private:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="any">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: @JustinBertram edited with more details

Comment: @JustinBertram: <interface name="any">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>   this configuration was done by another guy, didn't notice.

Comment: @JustinBertram put default-interface to "public", but receiving same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the fact that the `default-interface` of your `socket-binding-group` is `any` and the `any` interface is defined like so:

```xml
<interface name="any">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```

This means that any `socket-binding` which does not explicitly configure its `interface` will be using the `any` interface. This includes the `http` `socket-binding` which is used by Artemis. The `any` `interface` is *not* using any of the system properties you have defined for binding the server to a particular interface. Instead it will use `0.0.0.0` which is problematic for the Artemis configuration (as noted in the log). I recommend you set `default-interface="public"` in your `socket-binding-group`.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote configurations and now sounds the servers are communicating. Next step: make work with tcpping